# brew start and brew restart wont start service

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I installed mysql@5.7 using brew. After installing, I started the service using `brew services start mysql@5.7`. Checking using `brew services` shows its working fine.

In any attempt after the first though, the behavior is different. I run `brew services start mysql@5.7` and I get:

```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/505 /Users/Mahmoud/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist` exited with 5.
```

If I then try to restart the service, using `brew services restart mysql@5.7` I get

```
Stopping `mysql@5.7`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mysql@5.7` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7)
==> Successfully started `mysql@5.7` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7)
```

but an inspection using `brew services` would show that the service has been stopped:

```
Name      Status  User File
mysql@5.7 stopped root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist
```

Stopping the service manually using `brew services stop mysql@5.7` and starting again hasn't worked as well.

Tried as well to uninstall using `brew uninstall mysql@5.7` and re-installing using `brew install mysql@5.7` but the problem persists. I tried looking all around but I don't see anyone having this same problem. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Environment: M1 MPB, OSX 12.4

Spent a full day on this and finally came to a solution that worked.

Stop the service with `brew services stop mysql@5.7`

Remove the launch agent file `rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist`

Unlink the service if it was linked `brew unlink mysql@5.7`

Uninstall the service `brew uninstall mysql@5.7`

Then I removed the mysql data directory, suggested above. This wasn't in the `/usr/local/var/mysql` on my machine, but rather `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql`

So `rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql`

This wasn't the last step for me. Reinstalling at this point gave me a bunch of errors and the brew post install steps failed. Most of the errors pointed to my `my.cnf` file. I found that removing this file before attempting to reinstall prevented those errors.

I made a backup of this file just in case this caused more issues.

`cp /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf.backup`

Then, `rm /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf`

Note: this file may be in a different location on your machine.

Ok, now do a fresh install.

`brew install mysql@5.7`

`brew link mysql@5.7 --force`

If you link the package, you can add it to your path following the brew log suggestion. So add, `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"` to your `~/.zshrc`.

Verify the service is available with `brew services list` or `brew services`.

If you see mysql@5.7 there, go ahead and start it with `brew services start mysql@5.7`

Comment: This one solved it for me, thanks!

Comment: Yes, this should be marked the answer as it covers the issue more broadly.

Comment: This did not work for me. M1 Pro, OS: Ventura 13.2.1. Error: 
`❯ brew services start mysql@5.7
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/mariusz/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist` exited with 5.`

Comment: But this will delete all of my databases too. I'll have to reinstall them from scratch. Uninstalling and reinstalling something isn't really a solution if you ask me

Comment: work like a charm for mariadb@10.4. Thanks a lot! you can also get a status by brew services info mariadb@10.4

Comment: fantastic.. great answer.. worked when followed exactly same steps

Comment: Solved in Oct 2023, nice

Comment: I was initially following the steps above but without any version number as I was okay with installing the latest version. but for some reasons, the error persisted untill I finally resorted to adding a version number `8.0` so instead of `brew install mysql`, I did `brew install mysql@8.0`

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue today and noticed I already had data in the `/usr/local/var/mysql/` directory, probably from a previous install.

I didn't care about losing anything within the directory so I removed it all `rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql` and ran `brew uninstall mysql@5.7` and `brew install mysql@5.7`.

When I next checked `brew services list` it was already running, something that didn't happen before and it was all working.

Comment: Thank you! Been digging into this for hours - this resolved my issue. :)

Comment: Didn't do it for me. :(

Comment: The problem here is that brew uninstall mysql@5.7 uninstalls it for the user and not for the root user, so I kept getting into problems. Only when changed the user to root and uninstalled and re-installed did things get sorted

Answer (score 0):

Here's a key problem that I later discovered with my brew.

As `brew services` shows above, the user is root, not the current user.
This is insanely problematic and was the main cause of this problem. The solution to this was:

1. `sudo su`
2. `brew services` you should find the services taht are owned by root
3. `brew stop mysql@5.7` `brew uninstall mysql@5.7` Those basically uninstall mysql@5.7 for the root user
4. `exit` to get back to the user.
5. `brew install mysql@5.7`

Now the owner of the service is the current user, and say goodbye to the crazy behavior of brew